# How to get the full cmdline that is used to call a program, if the cmdline has multiple pipes

Tags: c++, c, linux

Im writing a framework, to track how people use my utilities, like example utility 'result'
So I want to put in piece of code into result.cxx main() that will log stuff like,

```
1. what arguments were given to result = argc, argv
2. what other programs were used to process stuff and pipe to my utility 'result'
```

eg:
Im trying to run a program 'result' which is provided input from pipes like

```
abc -e earg -t targ | process_stuff_out_data | result -s sarg
```

now in the result.cxx I use to capture piped input

```
    std::string piped_data;
    std::getline(std::cin, piped_data);
```

this works with cases like

```
    echo "1 2 3 " | result -i in_number
    // here the piped input is just "1 2 3" so i am able to log it from result
```

but wont work for cases where the output from the previous program is a stream of binary data

```
    abc -e earg -t targ | out_bin_data | result -s sarg
```

In this case i just want to

```
    LOG_PIPED_STUFF: abc -e earg -t targ | process_stuff_out_data
```

Comment: The "piped data" is nothing more than a standard input. Your program really doesn't care about the source of it. Therefore you problem is not where you think it is.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  Suppose you add, at a minimum, what you're getting in your local variable `piped_data` in the "working" and "not working" cases you provide.  Also, [mcve].

Comment: Are you looking for `/proc/self/exe` or `/proc/self/cmdline`? I don't really find it clear what you are asking.

Comment: Please edit the title of the post, as it is confusing. strings don't "execute a program".

Comment: It's just a guess, but can't you use the history command from within your program, to get the last executed statement?

Comment: the posted code (and the file name) are `C++`, not `C`  so please remove the `c` tag.

Answer (score 1):

std::getline won't return untill it reads a newline, see here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline
Use another separator token or just use another function to read from standard input while the data becomes availible.
You can use for example feof(stdin) to check if stdin has bytes availible and then fread() them.
If you are on linux you can use select(2) to wait for input on file descriptor 0.

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons you are not getting data

- the data is binary and doesn't have newlines. You need to use binary I/O calls.
- the data is buffered. You need to either flush the stdout of the middle process `process_stuff_out_data` if you can rewrite it, or just wait until `abc` and `process_stuff_out_data` exit.
- `process_stuff_out_data` is writing to stderr, not stdout. Or it is writing to the console (ugh), i.e. /dev/console.